# Is there a way to get all created context menus for a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a personal chrome extension to help me out with a part-time job in which the background script calls an API that pulls email template data from my personal Notion account. These various email templates are given their own context menu which, when clicked, enters the template into the email reply.

On install, a single context menu is created called "Load Emails" which calls the API to retrieve the data and create the rest of the context menus, I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve all the already created context menu data inside the onClicked callback so that I can check if a context menu with that id is already created or not before creating a new one (if I add a new email template to my Notion database).

The IDs that I'm using for the created context menus are the page id's from Notion so they are unique.

Looking at the documentation for context menus, the only options are create, remove, removeAll and update.

If there is a better way that I can achieve what I'm trying to do that works too.

Comment: Each extension has its own menu ids so it's not a problem.

Comment: No, but if I load the emails from the api again, it tries to create context menus again and I get an error in the console saying I can’t create context menus with duplicate ids. It’s not a huge problem but I’d rather not have this error.